# "Application failed codesign verification" - Pulling my hair out

Tags: validation, ios4, xcode4

I'm trying to submit an update to my app. I had messed up some files, so had to generate from scratch all of my the certificates, keys, and provisioning files. Would that be a problem for updating? I read someone saying that updates to the app HAVE to be done using the same provisioning file... that can't be true, can it? Otherwise, I'm in major trouble.

Anyhow, my archive builds keep failing validation. I have triple checked that I'm using the Store Distribution certificate for my release. I also ran codesign command and it came through fine. I have also checked the contents of MYAPP.app bundle and the "embedded.mobileprovision" is there. Why does it say "Failed to load"?

Below is the output I get in my log. Any ideas?

(using XCode 4.0.2)

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/anna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-fjmzhplryhwnsrgcsoyuivpwrojd/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MYAPP.app/MYAPP
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
AssertMacros: signer,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 610
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 914
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/anna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-fjmzhplryhwnsrgcsoyuivpwrojd/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MYAPP.app/embedded.mobileprovision
 - (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving my issue by moving over to a different machine that had a clean install of all the dev tools. My original install got corrupted because I foolishly installed beta version over it and then tried to revert back, at which point codesign didn't want to play along anymore. I know that wasn't the smartest thing.. but sometimes you do things for the first time and learn the hard way :)

Anyhow, the good news is that new keys and certificates don't really mess things up and life can go on but watch where you install beta versions!

Comment: I am glad you solved this by changing machine.. I was also going to post you the same!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your distribution certificate from your system. Revoke that certificate from developer portal, create a new one. delete the old provision profile and create a new provision profile for app store and use that.

Comment: That's the stage I was at when I asked the question :S

Comment: No Anna you are not in trouble... I have also recreated my certificate and uploaded the updates of existing apps using that certificates

Answer (score 0):

In dev center you can read that it is critical to store your private key somewhere save. It also says that this private key cannot be reproduced if lost.

Therefore I think you are in trouble.

Comment: Yikes, I just saw that. Wish it was somewhere more prominent.. So now that I have new keys they are simply no good for my existing app? I can still test on my device though.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you should email apple and ask for guidance.

Comment: Yes, sounds like that is what I'll need to do. Thanks.